# How to bind to Published property with private setter

Tags: swiftui

Here is my data model:

```
@MainActor
class TestModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var data = ""
    
    private func randomAlphaNumericString(length: Int) -> String {
        let allowedChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
        let allowedCharsCount = UInt32(allowedChars.count)
        var randomString = ""

        for _ in 0 ..< length {
            let randomNum = Int(arc4random_uniform(allowedCharsCount))
            let randomIndex = allowedChars.index(allowedChars.startIndex, offsetBy: randomNum)
            let newCharacter = allowedChars[randomIndex]
            randomString += String(newCharacter)
        }

        return randomString
    }
    
    func update() {
        data = randomAlphaNumericString(length: 10)
    }
}
```

And the application view is:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    @StateObject var model = TestModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TestSubView(textData: $model.data)
            Button("Update") {
                model.update()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where a subview is defined as follows:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestSubView: View {
    @Binding var textData: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Data : \(textData)")
    }
}
```

With this code I get a compilation error because of a private setter for a model field data. How can I stay with a private setter and get this binding to work? What is the correct pattern to follow?

Comment: Oh... are you wanting the `TextSubView` to update the value of the `data` var? If not, then a `@Binding` is not what you need here. `@Binding` is used when you want a view to update a value and write that update back into your `view model`.

Comment: No, I just want a subview to be updated with an Observable object defined in a parent view.

Comment: Try `@State` instead of `@StateObject` (you don't need a class because you aren't doing anything async or using Combine, a struct would be fine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need a `@Binding` here at all. It looks like you `TextSubView` is not updating the text. You just want to make sure that it updates when the text updates.

So change your view like this...

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    @StateObject var model = TestModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TestSubView(textData: model.data)
            Button("Update") {
                model.update()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And your TextSubView like this...

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestSubView: View {
    let textData: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Data : \(textData)")
    }
}
```

Doing this removes anything in the code that allows your view to update the text. Which you weren't doing anyway.

Comment: great minds, my friend, great minds :D

Comment: @jrturton snap. 

Comment: @Fogmeister thanks for your help - I think I got Binding concept in a wrong way

Comment: No worries. And yeah, binding is useful for when you want the view to write back into the data. Otherwise it isn't needed :D

Answer (score 0):

If none of the views can edit `data`, then you don't need a binding. Just pass the value of `data` as a let property. Any subviews contained within the `TestView` will be reevaluated when the value changes anyway:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    @StateObject var model = TestModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TestSubView(textData: model.data)
            Button("Update") {
                model.update()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestSubView: View {
    let textData: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Data : \(textData)")
    }
}
```